# Trying to improve react app fetch request

Tags: javascript, reactjs, request, fetch-api

I have the following component in my react app in file 'Header.js':

```
import NavBtn from "./NavBtn";
import HomeBtn from "./HomeBtn";
import AccountActions from "./AccountActions";
import { useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { UserContext } from "../UserContext";

// import classes from "./Header.module.css"

function Header() {
  const {setUserInfo,userInfo} = useContext(UserContext);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/profile', {
      credentials: 'include',
    }).then(res => {
      res.json().then(userInfo => {
        setUserInfo(userInfo);
      });
    });
  }, []);

  function logout() {
    fetch('http://localhost:4000/logout', {
      credentials: 'include',
      method: 'POST',
    });
    setUserInfo(null);
  }

  const username = userInfo?.username;

  return (
    <div className="App-header">
      <NavBtn />
      <HomeBtn className=".HomeBtn" />
      {username && (
        <div>
          <Link to="/create">Create New Blog</Link>
          <button onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
        </div>
      )}
      {!username && (
        <div>
          <AccountActions className=".AccountActions" />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
}

export default Header;
```

with corresponding route '/profile' in index.js:

```
app.get("/profile", (req, res) => {
  const { token } = req.cookies;

  if (!token) {
    res.status(401).json({ error: "No user signed in"});
    return
  }
  jwt.verify(token, secret, {}, (err, info) => {
    if (err) {
      res.status(401).json({ error: "No user signed in"});
      return
    };
    res.json(info);
  });
});
```

I currently have a status code of 401 being sent in the response but am not sure if this is appropriate. I want the app to be able to be viewed just the same whether or not a user is logged in/out. The only differences I desire are that if a user is not logged in, they cannot create/edit posts and cannot view associated components to do so. I am achieving all desired outcomes except the 401 code makes it seem like the request is failing. I do not want it to fail if there is no user signed in but rather be able to function normally. As previously mentioned all components are being rendered properly I am just not sure if the 401 code is the right one to use or how to handle requests when there is no userInfo and associated token to send. I am new to web development so this could be a really bad question. How can I improve the code I have if any improvements need to be made to improve the efficacy of my component?

Comment: The request is failing, and that’s the correct thing to do. It’s unauthorized request so should be marked as such. The frontend will then do what it wants with that information, in this case not show things. The only thing missing is checking the status code in frontend, now it assumes any response contains valid user info.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen How do I go about making it so that users don't have to be signed in to view contents of the site that are not credential restricted? I am not having issues rendering the site but my friend that I am trying to collaborate with is. He is receiving errors 'Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch'. It is directly to do with the fetch request presented in my question. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: Returning 401 shouldn't cause an exception, that comes from elsewhere. You should handle exceptions in the fecth also and do what you need with that.